# dplyr: Filter multiple conditions with **selection NA values**

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, conditional-statements, na

**I am aware of** the all the question regarding the `filter multiple conditions` with very comprehensive answers such as [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647470/filter-multiple-conditions-dplyr), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647470/filter-multiple-conditions-dplyr), or even for removing `NA values`  [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665319/removing-na-in-dplyr-pipe), [Q4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988493/filter-based-on-na-in-dplyr).

But I have a different question, How I can do `filter` using `dplyr` or even `data.table` functions to keep both `NA` values and a `conditional parameters`?

as an example in the following I'd like to keep all of the values in `Var3` which is `>5` **PLUS** `NA` `values`.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

 Var1<- seq(1:5)
 Var2<- c("s", "a", "d", NA, NA)
 Var3<- c(NA, NA, 2, 5, 2) 
 Var4<- c(NA, 5, 1, 3,4)
 DT <- data.table(Var1,Var2,Var3, Var4) 
 DT
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1:    1    s   NA   NA
2:    2    a   NA    5
3:    3    d    2    1
4:    4   NA    5    3
5:    5   NA    2    4
```

The Expected results:

```
       Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
    1:    1    s   NA   NA
    2:    2    a   NA    5
    3:    3    d    2    1
    4:    5   NA    2    4
```

I have tried followings but not successful:

```
##Using dplyr::filter
 DT %>%  filter(!Var3 ==5)
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1    3    d    2    1
2    5 <NA>    2    4

# or

DT %>%  filter(Var3 <5 & is.na(Var3))
[1] Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

## using data.table 

 DT[DT[,.I[Var3 <5], Var1]$V1]
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1:   NA   NA   NA   NA
2:   NA   NA   NA   NA
3:    3    d    2    1
4:    5   NA    2    4
```

Any help with explanation is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table`, we use the following logic to filter the rows where 'Var3' is less than 5 and not an NA (`!is.na(Var3)`) or (`|`) if it is an NA

```
DT[(Var3 < 5& !is.na(Var3)) | is.na(Var3)]
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
#1:    1    s   NA   NA
#2:    2    a   NA    5
#3:    3    d    2    1
#4:    5   NA    2    4
```

---

If we need the `dplyr`, just use the same logic in `filter`

```
DT %>%
   filter((Var3 <5  & !is.na(Var3)) | is.na(Var3))
```

As @ycw mentioned the `& !is.na(Var3)` is not really needed but if we remove the `is.na(Var3)`, it becomes important

```
DT[, Var3 < 5 ]
#[1]    NA    NA  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

DT[, Var3 < 5  & !is.na(Var3)]
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Is `Var3 < 5 | is.na(Var3)` the same as `Var3 <5  & !is.na(Var3) | is.na(Var3)`?

Comment: @ycw It would be the same.  I am a bit cautious when dealing with NAs

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It is indeed a good idea to be cautious when dealing with `NA`.

Comment: Re your first line, I'd prefer to see parentheses. I have no idea how `x & y | z` gets evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work. Use `|` to indicate `or` for the filters. `dt2` is the expected output.

```
library(dplyr)

Var1 <- seq(1:5)
Var2 <- c("s", "a", "d", NA, NA)
Var3 <- c(NA, NA, 2, 5, 2) 
Var4 <- c(NA, 5, 1, 3, 4)

dt <- data_frame(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4)

dt2 <- dt %>% filter(Var3 < 5 | is.na(Var3))
```